# How can I move a variable from Javascript to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

This is my code.

```
<script>var test = window.location.hash.substr(1);      document.write(test);  </script>
```

And this is the result.     `access_token=CAAEfRaZBmZA7KHn26ZB1zaL2YUFUq5ZCN&amp;expires_in=7098`

I just want to contain only 'access_token=~~~~' this part in PHP Session variable. But when I searched, there is only the code which contains     `<script>var test = window.location.hash.substr(1);      document.write(test);  </script>` this part.

Is there any way? Help me please. I just want to contain 'access_token=~~~' here only.

Comment: Why people give me '-2'? Is this stupid question that much?

Comment: Maybe they think that someone able to write a php script would know what to do here, like using a string operation like 'test.split(";")[0]' to extract the wanted part.

Comment: can you post a sample URL here

Comment: Seeing the answer below, i think you should rephrase your question, i dont get it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript at all for this, you can do it completely in PHP. Try this:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if (isset($_GET['access_token']))
  {
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $_GET['access_token'];
  }
```

Comment: Nothing happens... In my situation, I have an URL like 'domain.com#access_token=dfjldajfsldkjfklsdfjsd~~'. And I selected and printed after # part by javascript code. And then, I want to contain 'access_token=~~~' this part in PHP variable. That's it. Did you understand my question?

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand. Why are you using a hash instead of a question mark? Hashes are used for anchor tags on pages (linking to the certain parts of a page) and question marks are used to pass variables via the URL.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter/979995#979995) but with one slite modification plus ajax or what ever method you need to use after getting the access token

```
var QueryString = function () {//you may need to call this at a different time if the hash changes after page load
    // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
    // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
    var query_string = {};
    var query = window.location.hash.substring(1);//**search was changed to hash
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      // If first entry with this name
      if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
        query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
      // If second entry with this name
      } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
        var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
        query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
      // If third or later entry with this name
      } else {
        query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
      }
    } 
  return query_string;
} ();
//then access it with or whatever you want to do at this point.
if(typeof QueryString.access_token !== 'undefined'){
    //then use ajax to send the access_token as a POST variable
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {access_token: QueryString.access_token},
        ...
    });
}
```

then with PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['access_token'])){
        $_SESSION['token'] = $_POST['access_token'];
    }
```